# Make Reference Images Visible in Animation

Tags: rendering, animation

I would like to make a reference image visible when I render my animation. I have animated the image as well. Is this possible to make visible in a rendered animation?

Comment: Why don't you try importing an image as plane and then you can animate it.

Comment: You can't make it visible as it is an empty, you need to use it as image texture on a plane or directly use image as plane as Aniruddhsinh says

Answer (score 1):

1. tap Shift - A -> add image as planes

[image]

2. choose rendered view (right most button)

[image]

3. optional: in shader editor connect the texture directly to the output, so the lighting is always as the original picture/movie

[image]

4. result:

[image]